# Struct in Ionic Framework

Tags: swift, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Does anyone know what is the equivalent of `Struct` in Ionic framework, using typescript. I want something like this:

```
struct MyStrings {
  struct AppErr {
    static let error1 = "error"
  }

  static let msg1 = "msg1"
}
```

The main aim is so I can be able to use the *struct* to save static strings, that will be easy to access, e.g `MyStrings.msg1` or `MyStrings.AppErr.error1`

Using an `interface` feels like extra work and definitely adds extra lines of code as you would string need to implement it somewhere.

Comment: You can use Interface for creating structure check this link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html